# c++ como ordenar numeros negativos

Tags: c++, poo, condiciones, dev-c++, ordenamiento

estoy haciendo una tarea que me pide ingresar las coordenadas de un triangulo y sin importar su orden calcular su area. Hasta ahorita lo que se me había ocurrido era reordenar las coordenadas en x,y del triangulo para ver cual sera la coordenada 1, 2 o 3. el punto es que la función que hice para ordenar los numero ingresados de menor a mayor no funciona muy bien en ciertos casos, más en especifico en los negativos, por ejemplo, me imprime que -2<-5, cuando debería ser alreves (-2>-5), les dejo el código con un caso de ejemplo que les digo que no corre bien:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

class Triangulo {
    public:
       int coord1X;
       int coord1Y;
       int coord2X;
       int coord2Y;
       int coord3X;
       int coord3Y;
       double calcularArea();

};

double posicion(double a, double b, double c, int pos){
    double aux[3], aux2=0;

    if(a<(b&&c)){
        aux[0] = a;
        if(b<c){
            aux[1] = b;
            aux[2] = c;
        } else if(c<b){
            aux[1]=c;
            aux[2]=b;   
        }
    }
    if(b<(a&&c)){
        aux[0] = b;
        if(a<c){
            aux[1] = a;
            aux[2] = c;
        } else if(c<a){
            aux[1]=c;
            aux[2]=a;
        }
    }
    if(c<(a&&b)){
        aux[0] = c;
        if(a<b){
            aux[1] = a;
            aux[2] = b;
        } else if(b<a){
            aux[1]=b;
            aux[2]=a;
        }
    }   
    


    if(a==b||a==c||b==c){
        return 1000;
    }   
    aux2=aux[pos];
    return aux2;

}
double Triangulo::calcularArea(){
    double el1, el2, area;
    area= (abs((coord1X*(coord2Y-coord3Y))+(coord2X*(coord3Y-coord1Y))+( 
    coord3X*(coord1Y-coord2Y))))/2;
    return area;
}

int main(){
    double x[3], y[3];
    Triangulo triangulo1;
    //(x1,y1)0
    triangulo1.coord1X = -3;
    triangulo1.coord1Y = -5;

    //(x2,y2)2
    triangulo1.coord2X = -2;
    triangulo1.coord2Y = -2;

    //(x3,y2)1
    triangulo1.coord3X = 1;
    triangulo1.coord3Y = 5;

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        x[i] = posicion( triangulo1.coord1X, triangulo1.coord2X,triangulo1.coord3X, i);
        y[i] = posicion( triangulo1.coord1Y, triangulo1.coord2Y, triangulo1.coord3Y, i);
    }

    triangulo1.coord1X = x[0];
    triangulo1.coord1Y = y[0];


    triangulo1.coord2X = x[1];
    triangulo1.coord2Y = y[1];


    triangulo1.coord3X = x[2];
    triangulo1.coord3Y = y[2];

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        cout<<x[i]<<endl;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        cout<<y[i]<<endl;
    }



    cout << "Area del triangulo: " << triangulo1.calcularArea();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿La función `posición` la usas para ordenar los vértices del triángulo? Podrías hacerla parte de la clase `Triangulo`. Por cierto, qué intentas hacer con `a<(b&&c)`? Por si a caso, `a<(b&&c)` != `(a < b) && (a < c)`

Answer (score 1):

No entiendo para qué quieres ordenar los números si el área del triángulo será exactamente la misma sea cual sea el orden de los puntos que lo conforman. Pero suponiendo que realmente necesitas ordenar esos números debes tener en cuenta que las coordenadas van a pares y deben ser ordenadas como tal, así que te aconsejo agrupar las coordenadas:

```
struct Punto {
    double x{}, y{};
};
```

Y tu código quedará un poco más limpio:

```
struct Triangulo {
    Punto a{}, b{}, c{};
    double calcularArea();
};
```

Para ordenar los puntos, debes averiguar si un punto es menor que otro, para eso basta con crear una función de comparación entre objetos `Punto`:

```
bool operator<(const Punto &a, const Punto &b) {
    return a.x == b.x ? a.y < b.y : a.x < b.x;
}
```

De esa manera puedes comprobar si un punto `a` es menor que un punto `b` sólo con la instrucción `a < b` y tomar las decisiones de ordenación pertinentes... pero yo personalmente no reinventaría la rueda, usaría [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) de la cabecera [`<algorithm>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm):

```
struct Triangulo {
    Punto puntos[3]{};
    double calcularArea() const {
        return (std::abs((puntos[0].x * (puntos[1].y - puntos[2].y)) + (puntos[1].x * (puntos[2].y - puntos[0].y)) + (puntos[2].x * (puntos[0].y - puntos[1].y)))) / 2;
    }
    void ordenaPuntos() {
        std::sort(puntos, puntos + 3);
    }
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &o, const Triangulo &t) {
    return o << "a[" << t.puntos[0].x << ", "  << t.puntos[0].y
        << "] b[" << t.puntos[1].x << ", " << t.puntos[1].y
        << "] c[" << t.puntos[2].x << ", " << t.puntos[2].y << "] area = " << t.calcularArea();
}
```

Como la ordenación funciona con colecciones de valores, he transformado los puntos del triángulo en una formación, con esos cambios tu código podría parecerse a:

```
Triangulo t1{-3, -5, -2, -2, 1, 5};
Triangulo t2{1, 5, -3, -5, -2, -2};
Triangulo t3{-2, -2, 1, 5, -3, -5};

std::cout << "Antes de ordenar: " << '\n'
    << "t1 = " << t1 << '\n'
    << "t2 = " << t2 << '\n'
    << "t3 = " << t3 << '\n';

t1.ordenaPuntos();
t2.ordenaPuntos();
t3.ordenaPuntos();

std::cout << "Despues de ordenar: " << '\n'
    << "t1 = " << t1 << '\n'
    << "t2 = " << t2 << '\n'
    << "t3 = " << t3 << '\n';
```

Que [muestra la siguiente salida](https://tio.run/##vVNNj5swED2HXzHKSlnokjQY7SUlrVbqD@iht90cjEFZJGIjY1eJUH57OjaYgHd7rcSX/d7MvJlnWNOsj4zdbg8VZ7UuSsgq0SpZ0tP34L7HTlS9TzdofRSyUu/ICpCumYJfmisBXbAohM7rEs7dNYZLd/0W4BXkQtQgmlJSJWQWMsFbF7KiMczWeWTSyFJpyYFuzrDfQ46vH7i4QIbfF9hZwHyfscAo4resKD/q2grp0zXm2b6mByPFiWO0Zrqm8gU7DaOhPIa4qmGrit2O5m0YDvHbA9b7Am6ZHFDE2iUnuIoieJrCUzaZsbc@m8zZ2xk7sWzkfwWCDVyDxR9RFSBkUXJqW2xDO7CF1dwKqYZE8ZACK6WRDTVOWNbgMaxGS7LQA5wp95Gu1NQYAVkGS/q6NG@1mY7JADEswUcuKNJgB8i9sGQa5gH3KOZFkX9F2Xn3MRTbgb3D577bk1NxBSda8TAKsLl7tyrp1mkM62e8SX8nMTybQzQhkc5sIjyjeqS0m2ZwZGNG7xkTWlm5L1yVLeAP1rsrd73uxzf@OAxBJWMziQ@RESI@lI5Q6iBTXSWb@TlC3Yp8spd@2POl/yzbRv9X8cM53KKLt9tf):

> ```
> Antes de ordenar: 
> t1 = a[-3, -5] b[-2, -2] c[1, 5] area = 1
> t2 = a[1, 5] b[-3, -5] c[-2, -2] area = 1
> t3 = a[-2, -2] b[1, 5] c[-3, -5] area = 1
> Despues de ordenar: 
> t1 = a[-3, -5] b[-2, -2] c[1, 5] area = 1
> t2 = a[-3, -5] b[-2, -2] c[1, 5] area = 1
> t3 = a[-3, -5] b[-2, -2] c[1, 5] area = 1
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Siento que no estás seguro de cómo ordenar números.

Repasemos una secuencia básica para ordenar 3 números:

```
// Ordenar de menor a mayor.
int a = 7, b = 10, c = 4;
int ordenado[3];

// Si a es menor que b y c significa que es el menor de los 3
if (a < b && a < c)
{
    ordenado[0] = a;
    // Si b es menor que c significa que es el segundo menor
    if (b < c)
    {
        ordenado[1] = b;
        ordenado[2] = c;
    }
    // Sino, como son 3 elementos, la única posibilidad es que c sea mayor o igual a b
    else
    {
        ordenado[1] = c;
        ordenado[2] = b;
    }
}
else if (b < a && b < c)
{
    ordenado[0] = b;
    if (a < c)
    {
        ordenado[1] = a;
        ordenado[2] = c;
    }
    else
    {
        ordenado[1] = c;
        ordenado[2] = a;
    }
}
// Si las otras 2 condiciones no se cumplieron es porque c es el menor
else
{
    ordenado[0] = c;
    if (a < b)
    {
        ordenado[1] = a;
        ordenado[2] = b;
    }
    else
    {
        ordenado[1] = b;
        ordenado[2] = a;
    }
}
```

Si hay más elementos que ordenar, el código se volvería más largo y complejo. Para ese caso te recomiendo usar algún [algoritmo de ordenamiento](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_ordenamiento).

---

Quiero proponer una solución alternativa que involucra algo de conocimiento de vectores y fórmulas pero el orden no importa. En concreto, usar el producto cruz ya que es el área del paralelogramo formado por los dos vectores.

Para el triángulo simplemente es dividir el resultado por 2.

Siguiendo tu código, tendrías algo así:

```
#include <math.h>
double calcularArea()
{
    double x1 = coord2X - coord1X;
    double y1 = coord2Y - coord1Y;
    double x2 = coord3X - coord1X;
    double y2 = coord3Y - coord1Y;
    double area = (x1 * y2 - x2 * y1) / 2;
    // El producto cruz tiene signo así que lo quitas
    return abs(area);
}
```

---

Otra fórmula que puedes usar para calcular el área es la [fórmula de herón](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%B3rmula_de_Her%C3%B3n). Aunque es más cara computacionalmente porque involucra una raíz cuadrada. Si la eliges debes tener el cuidado de que la longitud de los lados sean positivas.